# OLS estimate of a linear model with dummy variable

Tags: regression, self-study, categorical-data, least-squares

I know a regression of y on x (dummy variable) and a constant term can be represented in the following form:
[image]

On the other hand OLS estimator can be presented in the following form:

[image]

I need to see how these two equations for Beta estimation are related to one another.

Comment: This looks like a [routine textbook style question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Tell me (you can work it out) - what's the value of $\bar x$? of $x_i-\bar x$ (for the two possible cases)? of $\bar y$ in terms of $\bar y_1$ and $\bar y_0$?

Comment: Yes this is a textbook question and your hint helped. Thanks!

Comment: If you got the question out, would you like to post an answer?

Comment: could you briefly talk about how to get the estimation for beta1 from the original regression model? how do you know beta_hat = y1_bar - y0_bar ?

Comment: Hi @Glen_b, I'm struggling to get an answer to a similar question. This time, it's the case of a simple linear regression with a three level categorical variable. Can you please provide me with any guidance? Here is the link of the question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/546082/least-squares-estimates-of-simple-linear-regression-with-three-level-categorical

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The model that we have is:
[image]

Knowing that X is a dummy variable, we can get the following:
[image]

Using the above information, we can substitute for components of OLS estimation and by simplifying we get:
[image]